# Stop AngularJs from creating new controller/$scope cache and use cached one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using $routeProvider every time user clicks on a link, a new $scope is being generated. That means all the data is lost. How can i make Angular use the same controller/$scope?

Explanation:

http://jsfiddle.net/mpKBh/1/
(click on links)

```
<a href='#'>First controller</a>
<a href='#/view'>Second controller</a>

$routeProvider.
  when('/', { template:"{{$id}}",controller: ContentListCtrl}).
  when('/view', {template:"{{$id}}",controller: ContentDetailCtrl}).
```

P.s. is it possible to know which controller is currently active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AngularJS, `$scope` is *not* meant to hold data that persists across your application. For that, you want to use a service that is injected into both controllers. If you provide more detail on what data you're missing across routes, I would be happy to revise this answer to include something a little more actionable.

In re your PS: You can inject the `$route` service to get information about the current route; the `$route.current.controller` property will give you the constructor function of the current route.

Comment: This answer is correct. You could also use Angular's $cacheFactory if you have specific data that you would like to cache, but it is definitely correct that $scope gets destroyed when you change routes.

If you don't want the $scope destroyed, and using services is not correct for your application, don't use routing and use includes instead.

Comment: I've implemented this http://jsfiddle.net/vojtajina/U7Bz9/ example for infinite scroll, but when i'm changing routes, loadMore is still left binded, so if I trigger the controller 10 times i have 10 loadMore instances listening and at each scroll there will be 10 requests. So i was hoping that if i could persist the controller i wouldn't receive unnecessary requests. Any work arounds?

Comment: @n0mercy I'm not sure I follow why you would get so many listeners - or for that matter even more than one. Can you add some routing to this and use some `console.log()` statements to show what you mean?

Comment: This is what i was talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/xrYPb/1/ i think the problem is that i'm using window.bind here. Am I right? http://jsfiddle.net/xrYPb/ this is the revision that always has 1 listener, but i need to bind to window scroll :/

Comment: Actually the question in a bit out of scope. Ill make a new thread with this concrete question. How to bind/unbind to 'window' in angular. Because i can't really find anything. Big thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For those researching how to "unbind" in AngularJS, he is a bit of info (related to the OP's last comment above)

When a view is destroyed, it's basically **marked** for garbage collection - but it's still there.  That is why you are getting multiple requests when a scroll happens - because it's still listening for events.

So the easiest way to deal with this (that I have found, though I'd like to learn of other ways) is to listen for the $destroy event and react on it.

You can "unbind/unlisten" for an event by keeping a reference to what is returned by the $on method.  Here is an example taken from a controller:

```
$scope.systemListener = $rootScope.$on("someEventYouListenTo", function (event, data) {
  console.log('Event received by ' + $scope.name);
});

$scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
    // Remove the listener
    $scope.systemListener();
});
```

Now those old scopes/views won't react to events anymore.

Hope that helps someone!