# AngularJS not caching my pages

Tags: angularjs, caching

I am using AngularJS 1.4.7 and I noticed that AngularJS doesn't cache any page. What I mean by this is that if I visit route A, then go to route B, and then go back to route A the page is cleared.

I've figured that the template is cached, however it looks like the scope is cleared. This is annoying as I have search pages and whenever the user goes to the details page and then goes back to the search results page the page is cleared.

How can I avoid that ?

PS: I haven't posted any sample since I don't know what's relevant but my controllers are very basic, and I'm after a general answer on angular.

Comment: I don't know how big your project is but if you would use Ionic, then you can make use of cached states: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/

Comment: Thanks a lot but this would be an overkill for this project. Actually I found the answer. This is not supported out-of-the-box by angular. This is very disappointing, one of the nicest features of Single Page Applications is their stateful nature, but angularjs promotes a stateless development on the front-end....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop AngularJs from creating new controller/$scope cache and use cached one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233307/stop-angularjs-from-creating-new-controller-scope-cache-and-use-cached-one)